# Drop all partitions from a hive table?

Tags: hive, elastic-map-reduce

How can I drop all partitions currently loaded in a Hive table?

I can drop a single partition with `alter table <table> drop partition(a=, b=...);`

I can load *all* partitions with the recover partitions statement. But I cannot seem to drop all partitions.

I'm using the latest Hive version supported by EMR, 0.8.1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of version 0.9.0 you can use [comparators](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2908) in the drop partition statement which may be used to drop all partitions at once.

An example, taken from the [drop_partitions_filter.q](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/branches/branch-0.9/ql/src/test/results/clientpositive/drop_partitions_filter.q.out) testcase :

```
create table ptestfilter (a string, b int) partitioned by (c string, d string);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='US', d=1);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='US', d=2);
alter table ptestFilter add partition (c='Uganda', d=2);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='Germany', d=2);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='Canada', d=3);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='Russia', d=3);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='Greece', d=2);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='India', d=3);
alter table ptestfilter add partition (c='France', d=4);

show partitions ptestfilter;
alter table ptestfilter drop partition (c>'0', d>'0');
show partitions ptestfilter;
```

Answer (score 14):

Hive allows you to use comparison operators (e.g. `>`, `<`, `=`, `<>` ) when selecting partitions.  For example, the following should drop all partitions in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PARTITION (partition_name > '0');
```

Answer (score 3):

create a new table t2 from existing table t1 like below.

```
 create table t2 as
    select * from t1;
```

drop old table t1

```
drop table t1;
```

now check if you have partitions on new table.

```
show partitions t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table using data from original table:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS
SELECT column_name_1, ..., column_name_N FROM t1;
```

Only case is that it should be done in non-strict mode:

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
```

I hope it helps. GL!

Comment: `FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: 1:23 Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned. Error encountered near token 't1'`

Comment: @MattJoiner Corrected, but full credit goes to Balaswamy vaddeman.

Answer (score -3):

```
truncate table table_name;
```

will delete all the partitions. This is useful especially if you want to drop partitioned table.